# $(x,y)\mapsto f(x)g(y)$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity, solution-verification, product-space

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces; $X\times Y$ carries the product topology.
Can someone provide me with an easy argument that for $f\in C(X,\mathbb{R})$ and $g\in  C(X,\mathbb{R})$
the mapping
$$
h\colon X\times Y \to \mathbb{R},\ (x,y)\mapsto f(x)g(y)
$$

is continuous?
I somehow struggle with this more than i should...
My first idea would be using something like nets:

We have $(x_i,y_i)\to(x,y) \text{ [in $X\times Y$]}\Leftrightarrow x_i \to x \text{[in $X$] and } y_i \to y\text{ [in $Y$]}$ for a net $(x_i,y_i)_{i\in I}$ in the product topology.
Therefore it's just
$$
\lim_{(x_i,y_i)\to (x,y)} f(x_i)g(y_i) = \lim_{\substack{x_i\to x\\ y_i \to y}} f(x_i)g(y_i) = f(x)g(y)
$$
but this feels too sloppy and not very enlightening.
Any comments or different approaches would be great.

Comment: Do you believe that the the multiplication map $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous? Then your map is a composition of continuous maps.

Comment: @Javi yeah i don't know how i missed that. It was a long day... Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The map$$\begin{array}{ccc}X\times Y&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R^2\\(x,y)&\mapsto&\bigl(f(x),g(y)\bigr)\end{array}$$is continuous, and so is the map$$\begin{array}{ccc}\Bbb R^2&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\(x,y)&\mapsto&xy.\end{array}$$So, you can express your function as the composition of two continuous functions, and that proves that it is continuous.

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was a better way but i somehow didn't see it.